# iOS crash report analysis

Tags: ios, crash

Apple has rejected my app 3 times due to a network issue where my app is not able to connect to the backend server to get the data. I have tested my domain name from deferent locations, changed the domain name servers and even the hosting and the same issue still occurs only for Apple testers

Even with reproduction of the issue using adhoc installation, did not reproduce the issue.

I have got the crash report below from Apple, but could not find the root cause.

Any help please

```
Incident Identifier: DF805260-ED5C-40ED-B506-3A63A8C5274B
CrashReporter Key:   2dc48ec828366e5774edfcf660269a89dd0361b4
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             iKhair [932]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/A03DC4DF-DEEE-4B69-A542-7DE0931AAB0F/iKhair.app/iKhair
Identifier:          com.qunatatel.ikhair
Version:             2.3.2 (2.3)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-06-09 06:44:03.749 -0700
Launch Time:         2015-06-09 06:43:14.897 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F69)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x1868e02d8 0x1980000e4 0x1867c3b34 0x1000bf0f4 0x1000bafc8 0x1000bb038 0x1000b77c4 0x18b355404 0x18b33e4e0 0x18b354da0 0x18b354a2c 0x18b34df68 0x18b32118c 0x18b5c2324 0x18b31f6a0 0x186898240 0x1868974e4 0x186895594 0x1867c12d4 0x18feaf6fc 0x18b386fac 0x1000642a8 0x19867ea08)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198797270 0x19877c000 + 111216
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019883516c 0x198830000 + 20844
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019870eb14 0x1986ac000 + 404244
3   iKhair                          0x00000001000e7300 0x100060000 + 553728
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001868e0694 0x1867b8000 + 1214100
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001980003b0 0x197ff8000 + 33712
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001977e9bb0 0x1977cc000 + 121776
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001977e9738 0x1977cc000 + 120632
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000198000290 0x197ff8000 + 33424
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001867c1380 0x1867b8000 + 37760
10  GraphicsServices                0x000000018feaf6f8 0x18fea4000 + 46840
11  UIKit                           0x000000018b386fa8 0x18b310000 + 487336
12  iKhair                          0x00000001000642a4 0x100060000 + 17060
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019867ea04 0x19867c000 + 10756

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019877cc24 0x19877c000 + 3108
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000198661e6c 0x198650000 + 73324
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000198653998 0x198650000 + 14744

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198797c78 0x19877c000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001988312d8 0x198830000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198830eec 0x198830000 + 3820

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019877ce0c 0x19877c000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019877cc84 0x19877c000 + 3204
2   iKhair                          0x00000001000f3554 0x100060000 + 603476
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198833dc4 0x198830000 + 15812
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198833d20 0x198830000 + 15648
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198830ef4 0x198830000 + 3828

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198797570 0x19877c000 + 111984
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001986b992c 0x1986ac000 + 55596
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000198723394 0x1986ac000 + 488340
3   iKhair                          0x0000000100252f60 0x100060000 + 2043744
4   Foundation                      0x00000001877e1db4 0x1876ec000 + 1007028
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198833dc4 0x198830000 + 15812
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198833d20 0x198830000 + 15648
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198830ef4 0x198830000 + 3828

Thread 5 name:  AFNetworking
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019877ce0c 0x19877c000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019877cc84 0x19877c000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186897720 0x1867b8000 + 915232
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186895674 0x1867b8000 + 906868
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001867c12d0 0x1867b8000 + 37584
5   Foundation                      0x00000001876f94c4 0x1876ec000 + 54468
6   Foundation                      0x000000018775380c 0x1876ec000 + 423948
7   iKhair                          0x000000010010c6bc 0x100060000 + 706236
8   Foundation                      0x00000001877e1db4 0x1876ec000 + 1007028
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198833dc4 0x198830000 + 15812
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198833d20 0x198830000 + 15648
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198830ef4 0x198830000 + 3828

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019877ce0c 0x19877c000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019877cc84 0x19877c000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186897720 0x1867b8000 + 915232
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186895674 0x1867b8000 + 906868
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001867c12d0 0x1867b8000 + 37584
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001862a2890 0x186204000 + 649360
6   Foundation                      0x00000001877e1db4 0x1876ec000 + 1007028
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198833dc4 0x198830000 + 15812
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198833d20 0x198830000 + 15648
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198830ef4 0x198830000 + 3828

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198797c78 0x19877c000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001988312d8 0x198830000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198830eec 0x198830000 + 3820

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198797498 0x19877c000 + 111768
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018689d124 0x1867b8000 + 938276
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198833dc4 0x198830000 + 15812
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198833d20 0x198830000 + 15648
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198830ef4 0x198830000 + 3828

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019877ce0c 0x19877c000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019877cc84 0x19877c000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186897720 0x1867b8000 + 915232
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186895674 0x1867b8000 + 906868
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001867c12d0 0x1867b8000 + 37584
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186813358 0x1867b8000 + 373592
6   CoreMotion                      0x00000001871cc364 0x187184000 + 295780
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198833dc4 0x198830000 + 15812
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198833d20 0x198830000 + 15648
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198830ef4 0x198830000 + 3828

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198797c78 0x19877c000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001988312d8 0x198830000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198830eec 0x198830000 + 3820

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198797c78 0x19877c000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001988312d8 0x198830000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198830eec 0x198830000 + 3820

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0xffffffffffffffff
    x4: 0x0000000000000010   x5: 0x0000000000000010   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x0000000000000018
   x12: 0x0000000000000001  x13: 0x0000000000062aa8  x14: 0x0000000000000015  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x000000019c5e7310  x21: 0x0000000198ca5720  x22: 0x000000012cf5f8b0  x23: 0x0000000198c9df50
   x24: 0x000000019c5ce0a8  x25: 0x00000001702ab6a0  x26: 0x000000018bb1a7c3  x27: 0x0000000186afa83f
   x28: 0x000000016fd9f7c4  fp: 0x000000016fd9f740   lr: 0x0000000198835170
    sp: 0x000000016fd9f720   pc: 0x0000000198797270 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Comment: You need to symblicate the crash to identify the line where it crashes. Have you tested your app with no network connectivity?  Perhaps you are misunderstanding Apple's issue - it isn't that your app can't connect to your server it is that it crashes when it can't - they may deliberately blocking access to test that your app behaves correctly I.e. Reports an error when it can't connect. A crash is never acceptable

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed the issue , thanks to crittercism Symbolication service , i uploaded the file [appname].app.dSYM to crittercism website and got the trace files which has been recored their already transllated

what is strange is that issues occurs only iPhone6s and iPad Air only !

another more simpler way even is to use Xcode , you simple drag and drop the crashlog file to Xcode > Organizer >your iPhone/ipad Device Logs.
but note that crash file extension must be .crash

as described in http://just2us.com/2010/10/reading-iphone-crashlog/

Comment: So what was the issue actually?